# Default combobox first item mixed with database results

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox, ado.net

```
public static void fill_combo(string table, ComboBox cmb, string columns)
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            da = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT {columns} FROM [{table}]", conn);

            da.Fill(ds, table);
            cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[table];
            cmb.ValueMember = ds.Tables[table].Columns[0].ToString();
            cmb.DisplayMember = ds.Tables[table].Columns[1].ToString();

            cmb.SelectedItem = null;
            cmb.Text = "Select...";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");

        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hey guys.
With the code above i'm trying to get results from database and bind them to a combobox, but i want the first item to be a random "Select..." that isn't in the database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does something like this work?

 cmb.Items.Insert(0, "Select...");

Comment: @BenSteele No, Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - You can insert a `DataRow` containing desired values to the `DataTable`:

```
var connection = @"Your Connection String";
var command = "SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table1";
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connection))
    da.Fill(dt);
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = DBNull.Value;
row["Column2"] = "Select an Item";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Column1";
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Column2";
```

**Option 2 -** Instead of adding null data to the `DataTable`, you can set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` and set its `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and handle `DrawItem` event and draw the place holder when selected index is -1:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    var text = "Select an Item";
    if (e.Index > -1)
        text = combo.GetItemText(combo.Items[e.Index]);
    e.DrawBackground();
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, combo.Font,
        e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
}
```

To show the place holder, it's enough to set `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is being overthinked. After setting your source, just set the .Text property of the combobox to "Select Items...". Sure the placeholder text is not actually added to the Items list but it achieves the desired results for the user right?