# C# Combobox "Default Text" DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

When I change the combobox style to DropDownList, it works fine. But the thing is I can't display default text such as "Select a country" without making it as a option. "Select a country" should not be an option rather a default text which disappears when the user click on the combobox.

Comment: You will find this post useful: [Default combobox first item mixed with database results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40569021/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to put "Select A Country" as an actual selection but assign it to a string and then within your code, have that as your default value so:

```
string s = "Select A Country"
if(combobox.Text != s)
{
 combobox.Items.Remove(s);
}
```

this will remove the value once something else has been selected

Comment: Well kindy hacky way to do it, but i like it. Cheers mate.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure theres an easier way but just a quick fix :) np ~ @Printer